# Extracting a determined value from a list

Tags: python, split

I have a list from which I want to extract a number which corresponds to totalsec. I proceeded with the split method to constitute a list of list and then extract the totalsec but I got an error

> "list has no attribute split".

Here is my list:

```
['nbresets:0,totalsec:14,lossevtec:0,lossevt:0,sevlossec:0,sevloss:0,paclosevtec:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0,paclosevt:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0,dellosevtec:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0,dellosevt:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0,dursevlossec:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0,dursevloss:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0,nbfailures:0,notif:2']
```

the number I want to extract from this list is 14.

Please if you have any Idea how to do that please help!

Comment: Where is your code, including the line that creates the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot perform a split directly on the list, you can only perform a split on a string (since the list is already split). So iterate over your list of strings and split each of them.

I will shorten the code to make it more readable, just replace it with your list.

```
strings = ['nbresets:0,totalsec:14,lossevtec:0,lossevt:0']
for s in strings:
    # first split by comma to get the single entries
    for line in s.split(','):
        params = line.split(':')
        if params[0] == 'totalsec':
            print(params[1]) # this should return 14
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

my_lst = ['nbresets:0,totalsec:14,lossevtec:0,lossevt:0,sevlossec:0,sevloss:0,paclosevtec:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0,paclosevt:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0,dellosevtec:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0,dellosevt:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0,dursevlossec:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0,dursevloss:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0,nbfailures:0,notif:2']


print re.findall(pattern="totalsec:(\d+)", string=my_lst[0])[0]
```

output:

```
14
```

Comment: The output gives me : totalsec:14. But it gives me this error too:

Comment: AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-74-f92f03f9a73b> in <module>()
     17 print(liste_evt_contenu)
     18 
---> 19 print (liste_evt_contenu[0].split(",")[1]).split(":")[1]
     20 
     21 

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: @arijdaif try updated code also can you update your code in question

Comment: Thank you @Mahesh Karia, I updated the code but it  gives me "invalid syntax". I have tried the code of Mr Leon and it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a list as container? Your list has only one entry (everything between ' '). And you can only use split on a string.
Just split the string into a list. Then iterate over the list and extract the key / value pairs by again splitting:

```
myString = 'nbresets:0,totalsec:14,lossevtec:0,lossevt:0,sevlossec:0,sevloss:0,paclosevtec:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0,paclosevt:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0,dellosevtec:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0,dellosevt:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0,dursevlossec:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0,dursevloss:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0,nbfailures:0,notif:2'
result = {}
for item in myString.split(","):
    key, value = item.split(':', 1)
    result[key] = value

print(result['totalsec'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this also:-

```
for i in a:  #a is your list of data here
    gen = i.split(",")
    result = [x for x in gen if x.startswith('totalsec')] #which can be dynamic
    for st in result:
        name,value = st.split(":")
        print(value)
```